# How long should my microwave run?

Tags: code-golf, number

I'm hungry. Let's microwave something. Given a numerical input of between 1 and 4 digits, output the number of seconds that the microwave should run.

### Details

The trick is figuring out if the user is inputting seconds or a combination of seconds and minutes. The ones and the tens places should be interpreted as seconds and the hundreds and thousands places should be minutes. For example, the value `1234` should be interpreted as 12 minutes, 34 seconds and `9876` should be 98 minutes, 76 seconds. Typing `130` and `90` should both result in a cook time of 90 seconds.

Here are a few other inputs and outputs:

- 1 = 1
- 11 = 11
- 111 = 71
- 1111 = 671
- 9 = 9
- 99 = 99
- 999 = 639
- 9999 = 6039

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are not allowed. The winning entry must return the right answer when given any integer input from 1 to 9999.

Comment: @WheatWizard, I'm happy to edit the question. Do you have a suggestion for what I should say in the Details section? Maybe I could make this sentence clearer: "The ones and the tens places should be interpreted as seconds and the hundreds and thousands places should be minutes."

Comment: @WheatWizard I just added more detail, let me know if you think I should add more.

Comment: Does that work with an input of `9876`?

Comment: Strange, I was about to sandbox this exact challenge haha

Comment: What would the output be for `190`?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Most likely 150, 1 minute and 90 seconds

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda t:t-t/100*40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHEqkS3RN/QwEDLxOB/Wn6RQolCZp6CoY6CIRhDCCBpCURgDCEsrbgUFAqKMvNKFNI0SjT/AwA)

Comment: im confused about the order of operations...

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian I'm unsure about the source of the confusion, but maybe a fully parenthesized version helps: `t-((t/100)*40)`. The `/` is integer division in Python 2.

Comment: this also works in python 3

Comment: No in Python 3 it would have to be `t-t//100*40`

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
ìL ì60
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=7Ewg7DYw&input=OTk5OQ==) `ìL` converts to base-100, and `ì60` converts back to base 60, resulting in `floor(n/100)*60 + n%100`. Also works with hours (`10000 -> 3600`, the number of seconds in an hour).

Comment: Exactly what I had :)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth - <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Converts input to base 100, then interprets that as a base 60 number.

```
ijQ*TT60
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ijQ%2aTT60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A11%0A111%0A1111%0A9%0A99%0A999%0A9999&debug=0).

Answer (score 8):

## TI-Basic (83 series), 8 bytes

```
Ans-40int(sub(Ans
```

Requires OS version 1.15 or higher.

Answer (score 7):

### C, C++, Java, C#, D : 36 bytes

#### D : 35 bytes

#### C : 28 bytes

First time i have an answer that short !

```cpp
int r(int i){return i/100*60+i%100;}
```

D can have a special optimization because of the golfy template system :

```d
T r(T)(T i){return i/100*60+i%100;}
```

C has a special optimization with the implicit int :

```c
r(i){return i/100*60+i%100;}
```

Code to test

In **C** ( have to include `stdio.h` ) :

```c
int main() {
    int testArr[] = {1,11,111,1111,9,99,999,9999};
    for(int i=0;i<8; ++i) {
        printf("%d = %d\n",testArr[i],r(testArr[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[TIO Link](https://tio.run/##RU7LDsIgELz3K0hNE7CocDE2tCZ@h/ZgoK2bKDWUnhq@HQFtnOxs9pGdWbkbpPQb0PI5q66erIJx/zh7g4EsprOz0QgOnLHtkZVQhEI4D9qi1x00JmjJUEAc2G6yF2OuLWrQwimPkchpRasYiZUT6aQfg0U4g4YJqE8ClSWschFvE7Y9zgsV9Ap10zldHaClBv8bQr6KLuXfz0xkzn8A)

In **C++** ( have to include `iostream` ) :

```cpp
int main() {
    std::initializer_list<int> testList{
        1,11,111,1111,9,99,999,9999
    };

    for (auto x : testList) {
        std::cout << r(x) << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU3RCoMwDHz3K8LGsG6O2ZeBtfgF@4TBkNqNgLZSI8jEb3etMsMll8DlTnXd9aPUsqAhcCxMTCanaXAG8Maz7HzPLnjySzEvRzSqGWoNEm1PTldtGYWXtkLDEpgi8NVTLQQaJKwa/Gr3arAn6WUlkO7p4a9NGIqnPGBtnuZpHrB2vmrmIlr5bR2waiALI4jd5x@5xyo7EEjpRX4cBBwCOzYmgeOniYvNNZqXHw)

In **Java** :

```java
public class MainApp {

    int r(int i){return i/100*60+i%100;}

    public static void main(String[]a) {
        MainApp m = new MainApp();
        int testArr[] = new int[]{
                1,11,111,1111,9,99,999,9999
        };

        for (int v : testArr) {
            System.out.println(v + " = " + m.r(v));
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9LDoIwEN1ziomJSVFE2JggceEBXLkkLCpWU4RC2qHGEM6ObUX0ZX5t38y8llTTTdMyUV4fY9tdKl5AUVGl4ES5gH7kAkESG7nfS4adFMC3cRStdtGaL02RDqMHBlO3Qoom6YZfoTYzyBklF/cspz70jmjhptdwAMGe7kD8dH6025ApPEqZ5RPH3GX5r/@LOIitOY@DJEisOU9m7pB6c31rJLjfaNh/d/zrsji/FLI6bDoMWyMdK0E0rGFhlCxMrkNJtP8nd/A@cRjf)

In **C#**

```cs
class Program {
    int r(int i){return i/100*60+i%100;}
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var p = new Program();
        int[] testArr = new int[8]
        {
            1,11,111,1111,9,99,999,9999
        };
        foreach(int a in testArr) {
            Console.WriteLine(a + " = " + p.r(a));
        }
    }
}
```

In **D** ( have to import `std.stdio` ) ( exactly, i have no idea how to use arrays in D ) :

```d
void main() {
    int[] arr = [1,11,111,1111,9,9,999,9999];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        writeln(arr[i]," = ",r(arr[i]));
}
```

[TIO Link](https://tio.run/##LYvBCoMwDIbP7VMEYdDO4trLQLq9hTfxIOi2gLYj67aD@OxdlJF8JD/5MmScn5ESvNJQMRh9boBUo1UDqBca05sC4MlZezzbEg@8@DV/Ig4w9xiUhkUKDKntoCeCK7TOuK13nKm3qnfqzktxi6RYB2TVeh6X7a@axnBPD85lqaUQX8I0TkHxqcXOFCwXhv5Ray9XyD8)

Comment: The D test code be the footer of this TIO: https://tio.run/##LYvBCoMwDIbP7VMEYdDO4trLQLq9hTfxIOi2gLYj67aD@OxdlJF8JD/5MmScn5ESvNJQMRh9boBUo1UDqBca05sC4MlZezzbEg@8@DV/Ig4w9xiUhkUKDKntoCeCK7TOuK13nKm3qnfqzktxi6RYB2TVeh6X7a@axnBPD85lqaUQX8I0TkHxqcXOFCwXhv5Ray9XyD8, and I see you've learned the template system :). (There is a `foreach` in D, I just forgot how to use it sadly)

Comment: C can be golfed to [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##RU7LDsIgELz3K0hNE7CocDE2tCZ@h/ZgoK2bKDWUnhq@HQFtnOxs9pGdWbkbpPQb0PI5q66erIJx/zh7g4EsprOz0QgOnLHtkZVQhEI4D9qi1x00JmjJUEAc2G6yF2OuLWrQwimPkchpRasYiZUT6aQfg0U4g4YJqE8ClSWschFvE7Y9zgsV9Ap10zldHaClBv8bQr6KLuXfz0xkzn8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online") using C89 implicit-int.

Comment: You should post all these as separate answers.

Answer (score 6):

### [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 10 bytes

```dc
?9A~r60*+p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/e0rGuyMxAS7vg/39DQ0MA)

**Explanation:** in dc when you push sth. on the stack it goes on top

```dc
?         # read and push the input number on the stack
9A        # push 100: 9 * 10^1 + A[10] * 10^0 :D
~         # divide 2nd nr. by the top nr., push quotient, then remainder
r60*      # swap top 2 nr., then multiply the top by 60
+p        # add top 2 nr., then print result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) bc + sed, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@seshoumara](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59010/seshoumara).*

```bash
bc<<<0`sed 's/..\?$/*60+&/'`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PynZxsbGIKE4NUVBvVhfTy/GXkVfy8xAW01fPeH/f0sgAAA)

Takes input from stdin. Went for a more creative approach: inserts `*60+` before the last 1 or 2 digits, and prepends a `0` to the beginning to account for inputs with only 1 or 2 digits. The result is then passed to `bc`.

Comment: If you remove `-r` and use `\?`, you can loose 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 15+1(-p) bytes

```
/..$/;$_-=40*$`
```

- -l switch not counted because for tests readability

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fT09F31olXtfWxEBLJeH/f0MuQxACY0MuSy5LEAJjy3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

As a monadic link (thanks for the heads-up, caird!):

```
b³ḅ60
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p0OaHO1rNDP5bAsHh9v8A)

... Or as a full program:

```
bȷ2ḅ60
```

This can be ported easily to 05AB1E, so:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
тв60β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YtOFTWYG5zb9/28JBAA)

Simply converts the input integer to base **100** and then converts the result from base **60** to integer. Hence, it is equivalent to **Input % 100 + 60 * ⌊Input / 100⌋**

Comment: [As a function, 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p0OaHO1rNDP7//28JBAA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I think you meant [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p0OaHO1rNDP5bAsHh9v8A), but thanks for the heads-up anyway

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
t;f(){scanf("%d",&t);printf("%d",t%100+t/100*60);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/EOk1Ds7o4OTEvTUNJNUVJR61E07qgKDOvBMovUTU0MNAu0QeSWmYGmta1/4FyCrmJmXlAfUC9QAEA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0Szuii1pLQoT6FE1dDAQLtEH0hqmRlY1/7PzCtRyE3MzNPQ5KrmUgCCgiKgUJqGkmqKko5CmoYhEGhqWnPV/gcA): `f(t){return t%100+t/100*60;}`. [Functions are allowed to take input as arguments and output via their return values.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU9tC4IwEP6@XzEKYctV80ORTIN@R/khptZBzZgTBPG3r20mRcfdw70/d3J9k9IuQclHV1ZZa0poNvej1QRYT4c@h23C@WrPY4icI0YLyuCGeAQ66Mp0WuH/JoR8/XkFRSgeEHbiE6ZqzUnrc4FzPCQs8RosYSlLvQZLRxFG6kZPPDkXkB0EjmOY13l5aVetySLalW6hRxKV9KIWbCaCgmnyDShzl/@EdOIZA35e4QKN9g0) `f(i,x){x=i/100*60+i%100;}`

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##RU1hC4IwFPzur3gYwZazNijIpkG/o/wQU@tBzZgTBPG3L7eijruD43H3VHpTyi1Qq0df1XlnK2zX96NrCLKBjkOBKW4E56stl5NDbeF5RU3oGMEMn23d2ZMx5xIKGAUTnkGCZSzzDMomGSpNa4ivYcElYL6fLUm@cx4vM18bEi93FRxg9ouO2e8Jlgwa8k@Uflan4Ka2vdHAZTS5Nw) `f(i,x){x=i-i/100*40;}`

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 13 bytes

```java
n->n-n/100*40
```

Port of [*@ovs*' amazing Python 2 formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/52210).

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jc9NCoMwEAXgvaeYZSxoI@2mSHuDunFZukhjWmJ1FDMKpXj2NP5sS4QkMPM@eKQUg4iaVmFZvK2shDFwFRq/AYBGUt1TSAXZNM4LkGx6MUzdZnTXHUOCtIQMEM5gMbpghPuE892R23Qhbf@oHFnl0OgCatfCcuo0vm53EOFSkX8MqTpueopbF1GFDGPJknAu/J/7wQbhIydf7gcbhJdw308OqxiD0f4A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>38</s> 33 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
$args|%{$_-40*($_-replace'..?$')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1WiVe18RASwNIFaUW5CQmp6rr6dmrqGvW/q/l4jLUMQQhMDbUsdSxBCEwtgRqVVNJU1CJr/0PAA)

Uses the same formula popularizes by ovs. Truncating is still expensive in PowerShell. Now uses a better regex to instead rip the last one or two characters off to division.

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uEa1WiVe18RASwNIFaUW5CQmp6rr6dmrqGvW/q/l4jLUMQQhMDbUsdSxBCEwtgRqVVNJU1CJr/0PAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 21 bytes

```
a=>(a/100^0)*60+a%100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwEAC/0ksxqWuabUXNwX6kKC4aIYImJGn7/FSFGZjTLPSlMHrjYrHZSae5TdS@GN1Ryl7yWyVzuu6dnLejDkGEONlPFD9vomZvBDw4RVCgDk4V4ONZgmrqqhMrObZvZ0Z5lnEuFmu24TLw9Ac)

Comment: Save 4 bytes by using ovs's trick - a-(a/100^0)*40

Comment: @IanF1. Thanks, but I think it would be literally stealing their idea.

Comment: yeah you're right. Too enthusiastic, sorry.

Comment: @ThePirateBay You don't really live up to your name then ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
-40*&<.%&100
```

It's ovs' Python 2 solution expressed in J. It consist of a hook and a fork:

```
┌─┬───────────────────────┐
│-│┌──┬────────┬─────────┐│
│ ││40│┌─┬─┬──┐│┌─┬─┬───┐││
│ ││  ││*│&│<.│││%│&│100│││
│ ││  │└─┴─┴──┘│└─┴─┴───┘││
│ │└──┴────────┴─────────┘│
└─┴───────────────────────┘

       %&100  - divides the number by 100
   *&<.       - finds the floor of the left argument and multiplies it to the left arg.
 40           - 
-             - subtracts the result of the above fork from the input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxgq6dgoGClYPBf18RAS81GT1XN0MDgvyaXkp6CepqtlbqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagiGcYaiAYCKJItiWcAYSC5lp@f8/AA)

Comment: Same byte count as `60#.0 100#:]`.

Comment: @FrownyFrog - your solution looks prettier, cheers!

Comment: Galen, I think it might be because Frowny's has a smiley :]

Comment: @RGS Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 23 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1-%1/100*40
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Kevin outgolfed me in my own language... (using the approach from [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/60919)' answer)

```
2dH/40*-#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/98oxUPfxEBLV/n///@WQAAA)**

## 10 bytes

```
sjvj60*^+#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/784qyzLzEArTlv5////lkAAAA)**

```
s             \ Split input into digits
 jvj          \ Join the first two and the last two
    60*       \ Multiply the first by 60
       ^+     \ Add the values
         #    \ Print
```

## 11 bytes

For one byte more we can use the `Input % 100 + 60 * ⌊Input / 100⌋` approach:

```
H2d%}/60*+#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/DKEW1Vt/MQEs7/v///5ZAAAA)**

Comment: 9 bytes by creating a port of [@ovs' Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/52210): `2dH/40*-#`. Never programmed in Pushy before, but it seems like a pretty cool language. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it's quite a generic stack based language, I guess the only  slightly different thing it brings to the table is the double stack... but thank you, and thanks for the golf :)

Answer (score 2):

## bash, 20 bytes

```
echo $[$1-$1/100*40]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKmQmadgqGAIQmBsqGCpYAlCYGxpnZKvUJxaoqCS@T81OSNfQSVaxVBXxVDf0MBAy8Qg9n9Kfl7qfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 18 bytes

```hs
f t=t-t`div`100*40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hxLZEtyQhJbMswdDAQMvE4H9uYmaegq1CbmKBr4JGQVFmXomCnkK6pkK0oY6CIRhDCCBpCURgDCEsY/8DAA)

Anotha port.

### Pointfree solution, 21 bytes

```hs
(-)<*>(*40).(`div`40)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 11 bytes

```
.{100}
60$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkaCnzaWi9V@v2tDAoJbLzADE/m/IZQhCYGzIZcllCUJgbAkA)

Input and output [in unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary). The test suite converts from and to decimal for convenience.

Doing this kind of base conversion for only up to two digits is surprisingly simple to do in unary. We just match runs of 100 `1`s and replace them with 60 `1`s. Anything that's left over would correspond to the last two digits in the decimal representation and remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 19 bytes

```
/o
\i@/.'d%~'d:'<*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00FfTz1FtU49xUrdRkv7/39DIAAA)

#### Explanation

Too bad I removed *divmod* from the language, I guess...

```
/o
\i@/...
```

This is just the usual framework for linear programs with decimal I/O operating purely in Cardinal (arithmetic) mode.

```
.     Duplicate input.
'd%   Mod 100.
~     Swap with other copy.
'd:   Divide by 100.
'<*   Multiply by 60.
+     Add.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 19 bytes

```
?:_100%}#00/_60*{+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3ire0MBAtVbZwEA/3sxAq1pb8f9/Q0NDAA)

#### Explanation

```
?      Read input.
:      Duplicate.
_100%  Mod 100.
}      Move off to auxiliary stack.
#00/   Divide by 100, using the stack depth to get a 1, instead of _1.
_60*   Multiply by 60.
{+     Retrieve the earlier result and add it.
!      Print.
```

The IP then hits a dead end and starts moving backward. When it reaches the `/` it attempts a division by zero which terminates the program.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 29 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
?[A1]Mod 1E2+60*[Int(A1/100)]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```apl
60⊥0 100⊤⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wQzg0ddSw0UDA2A9JJHXYv@/3/Uu0pBA8jSSdM8tOJR72ZjAwMudVt1LqiYgiUQAAA)

**How?**

`0 100⊤` - encode in base 100, stopping at the second LSB, effectively producing `n ÷ 100, n % 100`.

`60⊥` - decode in base 60

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

Straightforward:

```
n->n\100*60+n%100
```

Unfortunately this nice method is simply too long to use:

```
n->[60,1]*divrem(n,100)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

```r
x=scan();x-x%/%100*40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTukK3QlVf1dDAQMvE4L8hlyEIgbEhlyWXJQiBseV/AA)

Comment: I created my own solution in R and it was far less elegant than this.

Comment: You can cut the `scan` since most of the answers just assume the variable is already defined.

Comment: The rules are so inconsistent with regards to that. One most other challenges you have to have a function or scan to capture the value.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 34 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(- n(*(floor n 100)40)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXoqDxXyMnMTcpJVEjT1NDVyFPQ0sjLSc/v0ghT8HQwEDTxEBTU/O/oaEhkAQA)

Another port of [@ovs' formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/52210).

Answer (score 2):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), <s>66</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

Thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for -16 bytes!

```
__=-~-~_-_
_-=_/(__<<__^__)**__*(__-~__<<-~__)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pt5Wt063Ll43nite1zZeXyM@3sYmPj4uPl5TSys@XgvIB8oCxUCk5v///y0tLQE)

---

### Explanation

```
                      # input is initially in _
__=-~-~_-_            # set __ to (2+input-input) = 2
_-=                   # subtract from _:
   _/                 # _ divided by:
     (__<<__^__)**__  # (2<<2 ^ 2) ** 2 = (8^2)**2 = 100
    *                 # multiplied by
     (__-~__<<-~__)   # (2 - ~2 << -~2) = 5 << 3 = 40
                      # value in _ is the implicit output
```

Comment: You can use `*=` and `-=` for [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pj7eVrdOty5eN54LyARytYAYyNQCsrXBCMjTtY3X14Dx9YFCmkBV////t7S0BAA). Or change to generating `5` on the second line for [-1 more](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pj7eVrdOty5eN54LyARygex4EFvLFs7WtY3X14iP1wYjfaCQplZ8/P///y0tLQE)

Comment: Or generate `10` for [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pt5Wt063Ll43niseyI6P19KIjwfy4zW54nVt4/WBgiCsBUPx////t7S0BAA)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks for the suggestions! I was able to get it one byte shorter by not defining `___`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
B60B100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18erPOoqfG/k5mBk6GBwf///6MNjYxNdCwtzM10DHUMQQiMDXUsdSxBCIwtYwE) Not very exciting, just converts to base 100 and back from base 60.

Comment: This is neat! Husk and other golf-oriented languages make my brain hurt, but in a good way.

Answer (score 2):

## [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), 45 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxDoMwEAR7XrGiwsiRbCkNWHkAHdRAEQUcubmLrPP7nROsdqac7/tXaxxfsdBHElMnBvmUkgnyWApPJJ1Y75zpny6cdIQaOUOQCKu38Be31IP@4taw4@AGujknLUXNW7QbtSY0rK0/)

```
f:=function(t) return t-QuoInt(t,100)*40;end;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4 bytes (8 nibbles)

```
`@60`@@
```

```
    `@      # convert input in command-line arg to base
      @     # 100 (default value for @ when no input from STDIN)
`@          # and convert from base
  60        # 60
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```julia
~x=x-x÷100*40
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsIwEEXX5hSzbCWWhEoli4pbzyBSUhslUmJJIqQgvZYH8GA1iTazeu/z59@fveTUzfPkardxnzclZL0l8/WhwQpjmws3AqQCLXjXSyVMlqMVx9BgaKEGM/TSZqmZQ/Hag7FaqhtaOTz6ysC1EUV2VBbDyX@2Z79w4MYIbWFyUNcwIqE6hFJISxLiiZEZ/FG/QlGkiAsH2SUJVv2VeWY/irhwkKpMFpWU7As)

Uses the same algorithm as Misha Lavrov's [TI-Basic solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147783/114865).

Julia supports [implicit multiplication](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#man-numeric-literal-coefficients) (`40x` instead of `40*x`), but it takes precedence over most other operators.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
т÷60*¹т%+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YtPh7WYGWod2XmxS1f7/3xIIAA)

Explanation:

```
т÷60*¹т%+

т         // Push number 100
 ÷        // Integer division with the input
  60      // Push number 60
    *     // Multiply with the previous result
     ¹    // Push input
      т   // Push 100 again
       %  // Modulo
        + // Add the first and the second result
```

Probably there is some trick with base conversions which can be achieved in 05AB1E, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 10 bytes

```
':Z/v40*-!
```

usage: `./mw code.mwg -i 9999`

### Explanation:

```
code       explanation                          stack

'          push input to stack                  [input]
 :         duplicate ToS                        [input, input]
  Z        push 100                             [input, input, 100]
   /v      integer division (divide and floor)  [input, ⌊input/100⌋]
     40    push 40                              [input, ⌊input/100⌋, 40]
       *   multiply                             [input, ⌊input/100⌋*40]
        -  subtract                             [input - ⌊input/100⌋*40]
         ! print
```

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 25 bytes

```
arg t
say t%100*60+t//100
```

(Just another translations of @ovs)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
т‰ć60*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YtOjhg1H2s0MtLT//zcEAgA)

## Explanation

```
         command                              current stack
т‰ć60*+  full program. push input implicitly  [1234]
т        push 100                             [1234] [100]
 ‰       push divmod                          [12, 34]
  ć      push head extracted (n[1:], n[0])    [34] [12]
   60*   multiply by 60                       [34] [720]
      +  add and display implicitly           [754]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 16 bytes

```arturo
$->t->t-40*t/100
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?KJXEFv)

Another port of ovs' [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/97916).

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 14 bytes

```
|s/100R1*40$-~
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cs%2F100R1*40%24-%7E&inputs=1111)

## Explanation

```
|                  parse input
 s                 save input to memeory
  /100             divide by 100
      R1           convert to int
        *40        multiply by 40
           $       swap with value in memory
            -~     subtract value in memory from top of stack, print implicitly
```

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 18 bytes

```
|s/100R1*60$%100+~
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cs%2F100R1*60%24%25100%2B%7E&inputs=9999)

There's probably some room to reduce the byte count if someone were to pass 100 as a hard-coded argument using `100&\|` instead of just `|`. Yes, that's a challenge!

## Explanation

```
|                         parse input
 s                        save input to memory slot 0 (also kept on top of the stack)
  /100                    divide by 100
      R1                  reformat to int (e.g. 1.52 -> 1)
        *60               multiply by 60
           $              swap value with the value in storage
            %100          mod 100
                +~        add this value to the value in storage, print implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 20 bytes

```
f(x)=x-40floor(.01x)
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wknlmc55uz)

Port of [ovs's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147787/91262)

Answer (score 1):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 29 bytes

[Run it on SageMathCell!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLSU1TSNMo0bQqSi0pLcpTKNHVKNHXNzQw0NQyMeDl4uVKyy9SKFHIzFOINtRRMARjCAEkLYEIjCGEZawVL5cCEBQUZeaVaICM1QQAk5gW4g==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
def f(t):return t-(t//100)*40
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ɦB60ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDOSVBNkI2MCVFMSVCOCU4QiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTk5OTkmZmxhZ3M9ZQ==)

Port of Mr. Xcoder's Jelly answer

##### Explanation

```python
ɦB60ḋ  # Implicit input
ɦB     # To base 100
  60ḋ  # From base 60
       # Implicit output
```